# Global Array undefined with FontLoader Function

Tags: three.js

Im pretty new, hope someone can help with this trivial question :)
The array is globaly defined `var textMeshes = [];` and a function to generate the text at a certain position The function works but i cannot access the array by index, I get a console error that textMeshes is not defined. But if i log textMeshes `console.log(textMeshes)` as hole array i see the array is filled. `console.log(textMeshes[0])` results in undefined. I guess the issue is because fontLoader loads asyncron but please correct me if im wrong =). I really appreciate your help!

`function addTextToScene (posX, posY, posZ, i){`

```
                var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
                fontLoader.load( 'fonts/droid/droid_sans_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

                    var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( '#' + i, {
                        font: font,
                        size: 16,
                        height: 5,
                        curveSegments: 12,
                        bevelEnabled: true,
                        bevelThickness: 1,
                        bevelSize: 0,
                        bevelSegments: 5
                    } );


                 textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial );

                 var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 100, emissive: 0xffffff});

                 textMesh.position.x = posX;
                 textMesh.position.y = posY+50;
                 textMesh.position.z = posZ-50;

                 textMeshes.push( textMesh );
                 scene.add( textMesh );


                } );




            }
```

Comment: Please try to share your code as live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks Mugen :) https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/15882/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: the `FontLoader.load()` callback is asynchronous, so `textMeshes` going to be empty until after its content is loaded. Only then will this line take place:

```
textMeshes.push( textMesh );
```

before that, `textMeshes[0]` is going to be `undefined` because texMeshes has nothing inside it; it has a length of 0.

This is not much of a Three.js question, but more of an AJAX question. You should read this discussion to get more acquainted with the topic: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks for the link i will read it asap, but this seems a good hint.